# Java JSON error

Tags: java, json

I have this code:

```
public void villageJson() throws JSONException{
        HashMap<String, Object> villageJson = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        villageJson.put("newShopTraps", obj.get("newShopTraps"));
        villageJson.put("cooldowns", obj.get("cooldowns"));
        villageJson.put("last_league_shuffle", obj.get("last_league_shuffle"));
        villageJson.put("newShopBuildings", obj.get("newShopBuildings"));
        villageJson.put("edit_mode_shown", obj.get("edit_mode_shown"));
        villageJson.put("last_news_seen", obj.get("last_news_seen"));
        villageJson.put("last_league_rank", obj.get("last_league_rank"));
        villageJson.put("newShopDecos", obj.get("newShopDecos"));

        JSONArray buildings = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray obstacles = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray builds = new JSONArray(obj.get("buildings").toString());
        for(int n = 0; n < builds.length(); n++)
        {
            JSONObject object = builds.getJSONObject(n);
            object.remove("hp");
            object.remove("reg");
            object.remove("res_time");
            object.remove("l1x");
            object.remove("l1y");
            object.remove("l2x");
            object.remove("l2y");
            object.remove("unit_prod");
            object.remove("units");
            buildings.put(object);
        }

        villageJson.put("buildings", buildings);
        villageJson.put("obstacles", obstacles);
        village = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(villageJson);
      }
```

`obj` is a JSONObject.

`village` is equal to:

```
"{\"newShopTraps\":{\"myArrayList\":[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},\"cooldowns\":{\"myArrayList\":[]},\"last_league_shuffle\":0,\"edit_mode_shown\":true,\"buildings\":{\"myArrayList\":[{\"map\":{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000001,\"x\":2,\"y\":2}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":4,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":27,\"y\":16}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":27,\"y\":19}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":17,\"y\":14}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000014,\"x\":19,\"y\":16}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000008,\"x\":23,\"y\":20}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000015,\"x\":28,\"y\":25}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":19,\"y\":23}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":21,\"y\":13}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":6,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":16,\"y\":18}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":4,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":13,\"y\":13}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":4,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":16,\"y\":10}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":20,\"y\":10}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":4,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":13,\"y\":17}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":3,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":24,\"y\":13}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":16,\"y\":21}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000005,\"x\":19,\"y\":20}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":5,\"data\":1000003,\"x\":23,\"y\":16}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":2,\"data\":1000000,\"x\":22,\"y\":24}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000006,\"x\":13,\"y\":20}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000002,\"x\":13,\"y\":10}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000004,\"x\":10,\"y\":7}},{\"map\":{\"lvl\":0,\"data\":1000007,\"x\":2,\"y\":38}}]},\"obstacles\":{\"myArrayList\":[]},\"last_news_seen\":136,\"newShopBuildings\":{\"myArrayList\":[2,0,4,2,4,2,3,1,2,2,75,0,1,1,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},\"last_league_rank\":0,\"newShopDecos\":{\"myArrayList\":[1,4,0,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]}}"
```

Which is what I want apart from randomly `myArrayList` and `map` have been added in. How can I fix this stuff?

Here is a working MCVE:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class splitJson{
        static JSONObject obj;
        static String village;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String json = "{\"android_client\":true,\"active_layout\":0,\"war_layout\":1,\"layout_state\":[0,0,0,0,0,0],\"buildings\":[{\"data\":1000001,\"lvl\":3,\"x\":2,\"y\":2,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":19,\"l1y\":19},{\"data\":1000004,\"lvl\":4,\"x\":27,\"y\":16,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":9,\"l1y\":26},{\"data\":1000000,\"lvl\":2,\"x\":27,\"y\":19,\"units\":[],\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":32,\"l1y\":20},{\"data\":1000015,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":17,\"y\":14,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":15,\"l1y\":30},{\"data\":1000014,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":19,\"y\":16,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":19,\"l1y\":23},{\"data\":1000008,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":23,\"y\":20,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":23,\"l1y\":23},{\"data\":1000015,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":28,\"y\":25,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":15,\"l1y\":13},{\"data\":1000002,\"lvl\":3,\"x\":19,\"y\":23,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":30,\"l1y\":27},{\"data\":1000003,\"lvl\":6,\"x\":21,\"y\":13,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":24,\"l1y\":19},{\"data\":1000005,\"lvl\":6,\"x\":16,\"y\":18,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":25,\"l1y\":27},{\"data\":1000006,\"lvl\":4,\"x\":13,\"y\":13,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"unit_prod\":{\"unit_type\":0},\"l1x\":27,\"l1y\":15},{\"data\":1000006,\"lvl\":4,\"x\":16,\"y\":10,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"unit_prod\":{\"unit_type\":0},\"l1x\":17,\"l1y\":26},{\"data\":1000002,\"lvl\":3,\"x\":20,\"y\":10,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":20,\"l1y\":10},{\"data\":1000004,\"lvl\":4,\"x\":13,\"y\":17,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":9,\"l1y\":21},{\"data\":1000002,\"lvl\":3,\"x\":24,\"y\":13,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":13,\"l1y\":25},{\"data\":1000004,\"lvl\":2,\"x\":16,\"y\":21,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":22,\"l1y\":14},{\"data\":1000005,\"lvl\":5,\"x\":19,\"y\":20,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":21,\"l1y\":27},{\"data\":1000003,\"lvl\":5,\"x\":23,\"y\":16,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":27,\"l1y\":23},{\"data\":1000000,\"lvl\":2,\"x\":22,\"y\":24,\"units\":[],\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"l1x\":8,\"l1y\":14},{\"data\":1000006,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":13,\"y\":20,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"unit_prod\":{\"unit_type\":0},\"l1x\":18,\"l1y\":14},{\"data\":1000002,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":13,\"y\":10,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":28,\"l1y\":19},{\"data\":1000004,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":10,\"y\":7,\"hp\":0,\"reg\":false,\"res_time\":0,\"l1x\":14,\"l1y\":16},{\"data\":1000007,\"lvl\":0,\"x\":2,\"y\":38,\"l1x\":13,\"l1y\":20}],\"obstacles\":[{\"data\":8000007,\"x\":5,\"y\":13,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000007,\"x\":15,\"y\":29,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":29,\"y\":4,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":20,\"y\":4,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":37,\"y\":18,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000007,\"x\":6,\"y\":4,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":20,\"y\":36,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":5,\"y\":29,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":8,\"y\":10,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":5,\"y\":17,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000001,\"x\":9,\"y\":4,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000001,\"x\":13,\"y\":31,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000001,\"x\":7,\"y\":35,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000007,\"x\":4,\"y\":9,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":32,\"y\":28,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":34,\"y\":13,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000001,\"x\":35,\"y\":5,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000010,\"x\":14,\"y\":5,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000013,\"x\":34,\"y\":33,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000014,\"x\":10,\"y\":17,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000014,\"x\":24,\"y\":7,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":27,\"y\":35,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":25,\"y\":35,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":26,\"y\":30,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000001,\"x\":28,\"y\":31,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000014,\"x\":28,\"y\":29,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000005,\"x\":1,\"y\":34,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":39,\"y\":8,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000006,\"x\":10,\"y\":22,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000010,\"x\":24,\"y\":1,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000006,\"x\":15,\"y\":1,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":41,\"y\":5,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":40,\"y\":38,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":41,\"y\":41,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":17,\"y\":5,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000006,\"x\":20,\"y\":7,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000007,\"x\":0,\"y\":21,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000010,\"x\":17,\"y\":40,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000000,\"x\":25,\"y\":40,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000013,\"x\":21,\"y\":31,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000030,\"x\":1,\"y\":12,\"loot_multiply_ver\":2},{\"data\":8000009,\"x\":20,\"y\":26,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000009,\"x\":21,\"y\":26,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1},{\"data\":8000009,\"x\":26,\"y\":21,\"loot_multiply_ver\":1}],\"decos\":[],\"respawnVars\":{\"secondsFromLastRespawn\":22339,\"respawnSeed\":619813173,\"obstacleClearCounter\":15,\"time_to_gembox_drop\":46271,\"time_in_gembox_period\":527175},\"cooldowns\":[],\"newShopBuildings\":[2,0,4,2,4,2,3,1,2,2,75,0,1,1,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\"newShopTraps\":[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\"newShopDecos\":[1,4,0,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],\"last_league_rank\":0,\"last_alliance_level\":6,\"last_league_shuffle\":0,\"last_season_seen\":-1,\"last_news_seen\":136,\"edit_mode_shown\":true,\"troop_req_msg\":\"2 lvl 6 loond for war.\",\"war_tutorials_seen\":0,\"war_base\":true,\"help_opened\":false,\"bool_layout_edit_shown_erase\":false}";
        obj = new JSONObject(json);
        villageJson();
      }

      public static void villageJson() throws JSONException{
        HashMap<String, Object> villageJson = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        villageJson.put("newShopTraps", obj.get("newShopTraps"));
        villageJson.put("cooldowns", obj.get("cooldowns"));
        villageJson.put("last_league_shuffle", obj.get("last_league_shuffle"));
        villageJson.put("newShopBuildings", obj.get("newShopBuildings"));
        villageJson.put("edit_mode_shown", obj.get("edit_mode_shown"));
        villageJson.put("last_news_seen", obj.get("last_news_seen"));
        villageJson.put("last_league_rank", obj.get("last_league_rank"));
        villageJson.put("newShopDecos", obj.get("newShopDecos"));

        JSONArray buildings = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray obstacles = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray builds = new JSONArray(obj.get("buildings").toString());
        for(int n = 0; n < builds.length(); n++)
        {
            JSONObject object = builds.getJSONObject(n);
            object.remove("hp");
            object.remove("reg");
            object.remove("res_time");
            object.remove("l1x");
            object.remove("l1y");
            object.remove("l2x");
            object.remove("l2y");
            object.remove("unit_prod");
            object.remove("units");
            buildings.put(object);
        }

        villageJson.put("buildings", buildings);
        villageJson.put("obstacles", obstacles);
        village = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(villageJson);
        System.out.println(village);
      }

}
```

Comment: What is the value of villageJson? You can try `String village = new JSONObject(villageJson).toString();`

Comment: Thanks man @ntsh post as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use Gson here. Just use [JSONObject constructor](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.util.Map%29) to convert map to json:

```
String village = new JSONObject(villageJson).toString();
```